# Angular 4 ngFor looping through array of objects with HTML

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, for-loop, ngfor

I'm using Angular 4 and I want to loop through an array of objects and display the information in Angular Material grids tiles. My html (app.component.html) looks a bit like this

```
<div class="list" *ngIf="listContacts == true">
 <mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="2:1" *ngFor="let i of contacts">
  <mat-grid-tile>
    <div class="card">
      <img src={{contacts[i].image}} alt="picture">
      <h2>{{contacts[i].name}}</h2>
    </div>
  </mat-grid-tile>
 </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

And contacts is an array of objects inside app.component.ts. There are NINE objects within contacts but for simplicity I've only put two here.

```
export class AppComponent {
// array of contact objects
contacts = [
{
  name: "Robbie Peck",
  image: "src/assets/robbie.jpg",
}, 
{
  name: "Jenny Sweets",
  image: "src/assets/jenny.jpg",
}, 

...

]
}
```

So rather than have nine different 's appear, each with their own information (looping i through contacts), I only have one and the console shows an error where it doesn't recognize contacts[i]. What have I done wrong? How can I get the  to have 9 's, each with name and image i within the contacts object in the typescript (app.component.ts) file?

Comment: The full and exact error message would be quite helpful

Comment: Should be i.name, i.image etc not contacts[i]. i is an object of type contact not and index

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to pass the index, you can just use the variable **`i`** and access **`i.image`** and **`i.name`**

```
<mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="2:1" *ngFor="let i of contacts" >
 <mat-grid-tile>
    <div class="card">
      <img src={{i.image}} alt="picture">
      <h2>{{i.name}}</h2>
    </div>
  </mat-grid-tile>
```